# Visual Studio plugin that shows open files

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a Visual Studio plugin that lists all open files in the current solution?  I am envisioning a popout pane that simply lists the open files in alpha order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the down arrow on the right of the tab bar, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

Or, click the Window menu, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.